# SSL/TLS Error during connecting vCenter via VMware Web Services SDK

Tags: c#, web-services, vmware, vmware-sdk

I'd like to write some application to manage vSphere environment but first I want to try SDK_5.5 Samples. After building solution I tried to run simpleclient.exe and I've received following message: "Could not establish a trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel".

Here is the command I'm typing to run the program:
SimpleClient.exe --url https://192.168.xxx.xxx/sdk --username administrator@vsphere.local --disablesso

I've installed esxi 5.5 and vCenter with default settings. Is there something i'm missing with certs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wired thing... The problem was I didn't place username in " "... after that everything works fine.